# Spree and unit testing

Tags: unit-testing, spree

I've been trying to run some unit tests in my spree application, which involves creating a new Order. The first hurdle I ran into had to do with countries not loading, due to seed data not being entered in the test database. A question was posted about it here, if you want extra credit work: https://github.com/spree/spree/issues/5308

However, I was able to bypass that issue by inventing a country inside the test, for the sake of testing the rest of my code. I've tried doing the same for a variant, but I keep running into this error:

```
Error:
VariantTest#test_variant_test:
RuntimeError: No master variant found to infer price
test/models/variant_test.rb:10:in `block in <class:VariantTest>'
```

I created a second test to see if Variants were getting made at all, and I got the same error message. This is the test I've run:

```
require 'test_helper'

class VariantTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test "variant test" do
    f = Spree::Variant.new
    f.cost_price = 20
    f.sku = "test"
    f.is_master = true
    f.track_inventory = false
    f.save!

    test1 = Spree::Variant.find_by sku: "test"
    assert_not_nil(test1, "Variant wasn't created")
  end
end
```

I've tried creating two Variants, one of which is master and one of which is not, and testing the sku for the non-master variant, but I keep getting the exact same error message about the master variant not being found. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to answer your queestion: You need to set `price` for your variant. You will get then new error because you're missing `product` for that variant and so on.

Belive me, you really want  to use default factories with [FactoryGirl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl), you won't have to lose time reinventing the wheel. Just look at them [here](https://github.com/spree/spree/tree/master/core/lib/spree/testing_support/factories) or directly at [variant factory](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/core/lib/spree/testing_support/factories/variant_factory.rb), if you'll have any questions about them just ask.

Comment: Yeah, the next time I do this I will definitely be using FactoryGirl. Thanks!